# Why may setting Image or BackgroundImage have no effect?

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to figure out why  setting a control's `Image` property on one form has no visible effect, while setting the same property of a control that belongs to a different Form works perfectly. My target form has non-default background color (it's all black with a white foreground color) and no border style. Setting the other form to the same color and border style does not affect its ability to display images. So what's wrong with my target form? What settings could I have tripped that make my image sets do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I was initializing the form from within itself, so it had no suitable graphics context to give itself to display images on. Moving the form's field outside its own class to the main form solved the problem.